# Intent to Open default desktop screen in default launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher

I know the Intent to open the default launcher in Android but I need to start launcher and open the default desktop page.
Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to request a particular homescreen using the [stock Android launcher](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3.git/+/master/src/com/android/launcher3/Launcher.java).

The launcher defines the default screen using:

```
static final int DEFAULT_SCREEN = 2
```

And the only way to change it is by calling:

```
static void setScreen(int screen) {
        synchronized (sLock) {
            sScreen = screen;
        }
    }
```

But none of these are publically available to a third party developer and the app doesn't look for an `Intent` extra or anything that might indicate which screen you'd like to display.

Comment: @TalhaQ Maybe you meant to post a question? That's an entirely different topic than what the OP is asking about.

Comment: When I click the home button the system opens the default desktop screen or the app drawer if I'm in the default screen. These actions are controlled by the launcher or by the Android framework? Thanks

Comment: @TheMatrix The launcher. If you're satisfied with this answer, will you mark it as accepted, please?